# Prevent Context Menu from closing on clicking item (specifically checkbox item)

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-context

If I have a checkable item in a Context Menu or ordianry Menu, how do I prevent the menu from closing when the item is selected?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what library your using to create the Menu (ABS/ABC/?) but generally I think you'd just have to `return false` when handling an item click. The `return` value lets the system know whether the click was handled or not. Normally you'd set it to `true`, then the system will do its default behavior of closing the menu.  Here's an example for a contextual menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            editNote(info.id);
            return true; // return false here
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteNote(info.id);
            return true; // or here
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Things have probably changed since the Android 2.x SDK which I was using when I asked the question.

Comment: Doesn't work. Returning false or even returning true still results in the context menu having its default behavior of dismissal when an item is selected.

Answer (score -1):

In my case adding these two lines worked:

```
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
item.setActionView(new View(getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: a more complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727213/2445763

Answer (score -5):

Use the following property:

```
<MenuItem IsCheckable="True" StaysOpenOnClick="True"...
```

Comment: That is not currently a property you can set for Android