# Menu item click hides popup

Tags: android, menuitem

I have list of items with checkboxes in my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ListActivity">
    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="all"
        android:orderInCategory="1">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/all"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:title="@string/category_all" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/entertainment"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="@string/category_1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sport"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="@string/category_2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/recreation"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="@string/category_3" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

but if I click on any item is, the window closes. I know, it should work like this. But I need keep this popup open. Please help me somebody!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31727213/1979347

Comment: check ````setOnActionExpandListener```` method

Answer (score 1):

Try using "return false " in onOptionsItemSelected method .
hope it will work for you !!