# Prevent options menu from closing on OptionItemSelected

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-optionsmenu

I got an options menu with a bunch of checkboxes in it. I'd like to check a bunch of them on or off, but the menu closes automaticly every time I check just one. Can I prevent the menu from closing when an item has been selected? I'd also want to control *when* the closing happens and when it's prevented.

Activity.cs (excluding everything not related to options menu)

```
public class Activity: ReactiveActivity<ViewModel>, IAppCompatCallback
{

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        var inflater = MenuInflater;
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if(item.ItemId == Resource.Id.action_settings) {
           StartActivity(typeof(SettingsActivity));
        }
        else {
           //Code changing the view based on selections
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:title="Choose options...">
  <menu>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption1"
            android:title="Option 1" 
            android:checked="true" />
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption2"
            android:title="Option 2"
            android:checked="true" />
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption3"
            android:title="Option 3"
            android:checked="true" />
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption4"
            android:title="Option 4"
            android:checked="true" />
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption5"
            android:title="Option 5"
            android:checked="true" />
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption6"
            android:title="Option 6"
            android:checked="true" />
      <item android:id="@+id/checkOption7"
            android:title="Option 7"
            android:checked="true" />
    </group>
  </menu>
  </item>
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Did you tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726039/how-to-prevent-popup-menu-from-closing-on-checkbox-click/

Comment: @zkminusck I did notice that question, but I was having hard time traslating the solution to C# and Xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got an options menu with a bunch of checkboxes in it. I'd like to check a bunch of them on or off, but the menu closes automaticly every time I check just one. Can I prevent the menu from closing when an item has been selected? I'd also want to control when the closing happens and when it's prevented.

For Menus, I didn't find a proper way to control the closing behavior.

But for your requirement, `Dialog` is a much better choice:

1. remove the sub menu in your action.xml and add an id for `Choose Options...` Item:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:title="Choose options..." android:id="@+id/chooseOption"></item>
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
           android:title="Settings"
           android:showAsAction="never"/>
   </menu>
   ```
2. Create your `DialogFragment` together with `AlertDialog`:

   ```
   public class MyDialogFragment:DialogFragment
   {
       string[] Items { get; set; }
       bool[] CheckedItems { get; set; }

       public MyDialogFragment(string[] items,bool[] checkedItems)
       {
           Items = items;
           checkedItems = checkedItems;
       }
       public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity);
           builder.SetMultiChoiceItems(Items, CheckedItems, new DialogItemClickhandler());
           // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
           return builder.Create();
       } 
   }

   public class DialogItemClickhandler : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnMultiChoiceClickListener
   {
       public void OnClick(IDialogInterface dialog, int which, bool isChecked)
       {
          //Item Click Implementation
       }
   }
   ```
3. Open the dialog when user clicks the `Choose Options...` Menu Item:

   ```
   public class MainActivity : Activity
   {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           base.OnCreate(bundle);
           SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
       }


       public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
       {
           MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Actions, menu);
           return true;
       }

       public override bool OnMenuItemSelected(int featureId, IMenuItem item)
       {
           switch (item.ItemId)
           {
               case Resource.Id.chooseOption:
                   OpenDialogFragment();//Open the dialog
                   break;
               default:break;
           }
           return true;
       }

       private void OpenDialogFragment()
       {

           //init the Dialog items
           string[] items = new string[] {
               "Options 1",
               "Options 2",
               "Options 3",
               "Options 4",
               "Options 5",
               "Options 6"
           };

           bool[] checkedItems = new bool[] {
               true,
               false,
               true,
               false,
               true,
               false
           };
           MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment(items,checkedItems);
           dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "tag");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the in depth description of the implementation. I don't have time to properly test this solution yet, but once I do, I'll get back to this.

Answer (score 1):

My situation is the same, menu items with checkboxes.

I didn't find a way to prevent it from closing but as a hack I reopen the options menu as soon as it closes, there's a problem that I couldn't figure out how to fix though, while opening and closing the options menu there's an animation, and I couldn't find a way to disable it even looking around and finding possible answers, all failed.

In our app we created a Toolbar and set it up as an ActionBar, then on your code you override this method and call `toolbar.showOverflowMenu()` to reopen the menu:

```
/**
 * Handles the overflow menu closing event
 *
 * Due to a possible Android bug this is called twice!
 */
override fun onPanelClosed(featureId: Int, menu: Menu)
{
    if (something)    toolbar.showOverflowMenu()
}
```

You should use some rule to avoid having the menu opening itself non stop like the `if` statement on the example.

On the menu itself after the checkboxes I added an **OK** button, when the user clicks it I change a Boolean (something on the example) and avoid reopening the menu again.